# Adding -lboost_serialization to eclipse C++ IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

Actually I am using `boost libraries` which need `-lboost_serialization` while compilation. It works fine when I use it in `linux` like `g++ -stdc++17 -lboost_serialization`. However, it gives many errors that I think are linking errors when I run it via eclipse C++ IDE

> > ./binary_out_in.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::~common_oarchive()':
> >     /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:35: undefined reference to`boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()'
> >     ./binary_out_in.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~binary_oarchive_impl()':
> >     /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:38: undefined reference to`boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive >::~basic_binary_oprimitive()'
> >     ./binary_out_in.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::~common_iarchive()':
> >     /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:38: undefined reference to`boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::~basic_iarchive()'
> >     ./binary_out_in.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~binary_iarchive_impl()':
> >     /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:37: undefined reference to`boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive >::~basic_binary_iprimitive()'
> >     ./binary_out_in.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::binary_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)':
> >     /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:96: undefined reference to`boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive

I have linked `-lboost_serialization`, shown in the following fig, but still it gives the same issue. Do I need to some thing else?

[image]

Comment: add `boost_serialization` in Linker/Libraries.

Comment: @mch Should I also keep  `-lboost_serialization` as above

Comment: No. There can also be a problem with the cross-compilation. Your command line compilation uses the `g++`, while your eclipse project is a cross-compile-project. Try to compile in the command line with the cross compiler.

Comment: @mch Thank you, adding `boost_serialization` in Linker/Libraries works.

Comment: @mch consider copying your comment to the `Answer` area.

Comment: @jacknad okay, done. I thought there is a duplicate, but the only one I found was from 2009 and the path changed a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the library under `Project/Properties/C-C++Build/Settings/GCC C++ Linker (or Cross C++ Linker)/Libraries/Libraries(-l)`.

Click the `Add...` button to add `boost_serialization` without the `-l` before, Eclipse will add this automatically.